# Error parsing single digit date

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime, format

Code, simplified:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12:53 PM - Aug  6, 2016", "hh:mm tt - MMM d, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Says it can't recognize string as a valid datetime value. 
Only happens when day is a single digit. Source is third-party Web API, so changing the input string isn't a viable option (it should work like that)

Anyone sees something I don't?

Thanks

Comment: `Aug  6` have 2 spaces between them, does it have something to do with the error you got?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it, 'cause when the day is two digits, there's only one space. The spacing in here makes it easier to see than in VisualStudio. I'll have to notify the API provider, since it's clearly a formatting error. Thanks!

Comment: Voted to close as: "This question was caused by a problem _that can no longer be reproduced_ or a _simple typographical error_."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to remove whitespaces from the original string with Regex and change your parsing format as such:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Regex.Replace("12:53 PM - Aug  6, 2016", "\\s", ""), "hh:mmtt-MMMd,yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

hope that helps